# Automating file upload to website from desktop application

Tags: vb.net, file, select, upload, web

I have a program made in vb.net, which automates the filling in of a form, (I used setattribute and invokemember("onchange") and invokemember("click")) for this, and I also need a way to upload a file automatically,

It is an asp website

The website contains a button.
when it is clicked, a `filebrowserdialog` opens and I have to manually select the file to upload

Using the standard `browsercontrol` there is apparently no way to bypass the `openfilebrowser` window to upload the file,
I need to find a way to select automate the selecting of the file to upload to the website?
or does anyone know another way around it? maybe with another `browsercomponent`? or by packet manipulation?

the full website's link is , [z8games](http://support.z8games.com/webform_new.aspx?gid=), but you need account to view page , here s a download link with the HTML source code [mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/?oghwjn3f0wbiw5r)

I'm not a pro vb programmer so if it is advanced some explanation would be nice

Comment: this is the html code for the button if you'd need to know

Comment: <td align="left" class="style4" valign="middle" >
<span id="ctl00_ctl00_Main_Left_lblAttachment">Attachment</span>
(Max. file size = 32MB)

<input type="file" name="ctl00$ctl00$Main$Left$fu_attach_new" id="ctl00_ctl00_Main_Left_fu_attach_new" />

</td>

Comment: Do you have a way to inject Javascript into the page? If so you might be able to use the new HTML5 file upload API, which to my knowledge is the only way to upload a file from a web page without requiring that Browse dialog. I can't offer much more advice than that, but here's a link with more info about the HTML5 file APIs: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/file_access

Comment: P.S. I'd recommend giving your question a different title, like "Automating file upload to website from desktop application" since at first it sounds like it might be a simple ASP.NET question...or maybe I'm misunderstanding the question myself!

Comment: It might be better to edit your question rather than put links to source code in the comments.